# Surface integral over d-sphere for $|x-y|^{(2-d)}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for $\int_{S_{r}(0)}|x-y|^{2-d}dS_{y}$ for $x\neq 0$.

The parametrization is hard to work with and the integrand is not rotationally symmetric. I will post any updates.

any ideas

thank you

Comment: You say "surface", "sphere", then type $B_r(0)$ in the integral. Also, there's $n$ and $d$. I assumed $d$ is the dimension of ambient space.

Comment: Also, this is your $100$th question. What would be a proper way to celebrate? I suggest: by writing more coherent, carefully typed questions in the future. *Form matters*.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote $h(x)=\int_{S_r(0)}|x-y|^{2-d}\,dy$. The letter is $h$ because the function is harmonic when $|x|\ne r$. Also, $h$ is rotationally symmetric, being the potential of a rotationally symmetric measure. More precisely: if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then 
$$
h(Ux) = \int_{S_r(0)}|Ux-y|^{2-d}\,dy=\int_{S_r(0)}|x-U^{-1}y|^{2-d}\,dy
= \int_{S_r(0)}|x-z|^{2-d}\,dz
$$
via the change of variables $z=U^{-1}y$.

The family of rotationally symmetric harmonic functions is spanned by constant function $\mathbf 1$ and $|x|^{2-d}$.

- In $|x| <r$, since $h$ is harmonic at $0$, only the constant remains. Compute this constant by plugging $x=0$.
- In $|x|>r$, since $h\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, only a multiple of $|x|^{2-d}$ remains. Consider $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |x|^{d-2}h(x)$ to find the constant coefficient.

Comment: I suppose by "this" you mean the integrand. How did you get that h is rotationaly symmetric?

Comment: @TKM Yes. Edited to explain the symmetry, and to fix the radius of sphere (earlier I took it to be $1$ for some reason).